# Are there any typical papers on the impossibility of black-box reduction of circuits?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, cryptography, research

I am now considering the impossibility of black-box reductions between error-correcting codes and universal hashing without multiplicative overhead in depth. I could hardly find any classical papers on the limits of black-box reductions of boolean circuits. Are there any such literature that is worth referring to?

Comment: Consider adding tag [reference-request](/tags/reference-request/info). While anticipating an answer here, check out [CS theory@SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com//help/on-topic).